# Can automatically enumerate figures or keep tokens in matlab?

Tags: matlab

In a live script in matlab, I plot multiple figures, and  I use this code to enumerate the figures:

```
FigureQuantity=1
plot(data_1)
title('Figure '+string(FigureQuantity))
```

Then on another code section I do it again

```
FigureQuantity=FigureQuantity+1
plot(data_n)
title('Figure '+string(FigureQuantity))
```

The problem is that if I run the last code section again, FigureQuantity gets updated and the enumeration of figures gets broken.

There is any way to get the number of tokens ordered by his code appearance on the live script? (independent of how many times the section code is run)

I would like to keep tokens so I can mix inserted images and plots. And I want to export the document as PDF (not to show plots in an application or an independent window).
What I need is something like MS Word enumeration of figures and tables.

I found this Matlab documentation: [Number Section Headings, Table Titles, and Figure Captions Programmatically](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/number-section-headings-table-titles-and-figure-captions-programmatically.html), but it appears to be used for creation of MS Word or HTML documents, and not to enumerate images on Matlab live scripts.

I do not understand how to use it, or if that is his purpose on Matlab.

Comment: Why not manually assign a token to each figure? e.g. FigureQuantity = 5; ... ; FigureQuantity = 6;...

Comment: @Scott The point of the token is to have an automatic updating. If a figure is inserted, all the figures should be updated. Word also offers other data about the token, like the number of the page of a figure or table (to make index and links), but I don't expect Matlab to offer that feature. Maybe if a piece of code can know his page number, it can be stored in a sorted dictionary, and the order of the token can be extracted by the position in the dictionary.

Comment: Your question looks interesting, but I don't really understand what you want, or what you exactly mean by "token". In case it helps, you can access the current figures, or get the current amout of figures, with `figs = findobj('Type', 'figure'); numfigs = numel(figs);`. Or maybe the [figure's `Number` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#shared-Number) provides direcly what you want?

Comment: @Luis Mendo numel(findobj('Type', 'figure')) and get(gcf,'Number') always return 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're updating the data_n variable live as well; otherwise, if you're defining these variables manually then not doing so for the figure variables isn't really the solution I think you're looking for.

Why not for-loop through the figure updates?

```
for FigureQuantity = 1:numberOfFigureQuantities
    figure(FigureQuantity);
    hold on;
    plot(data_n(FigureQuantity))
    title(strcat('Figure Number: ',num2str(FigureQuantity)));
end
```

The figure count corresponding to the FigureQuantity will index the appropriate figure and will update that figure if it already existed. This is the solution I think you're looking for; if not, please clarify.

Comment: How do you update the title so every figure gets the correct title "figure xx"?

Comment: I just updated the comment: insert title() after the hold on in the for-loop.

Comment: Oh. I tried $for FigureQuantity = 1:numel(findobj('Type', 'figure'))$, but apparently it only works inside a section of code, and not on the entire document (it restarts the numeration from 1 on each section).